# Update a column of a table based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

I work in SQL Server and I have the table Customer which is empty and the table Manager which looks like the following:

```
___________________________
|         Manager         |
|=========================|
| ID   Cust     RefDate   |
|-------------------------|
|  1     A    2023-01-31  |
|  2     B    2023-02-28  |
|  3     C    2023-03-31  |
|  4     A    2023-04-30  |
|  5     B    2023-05-31  |
|  6     A       NULL     |
|________________________ |
```

Then, I insert from Manager table into the Customer table and now the Customer  table looks like this:

```
_______________________________________
|             Customer                |
|=====================================|
| ID   Cust     FROM          TO      |
|------------------------------------ |
|  1     A      NULL      2023-01-31  |
|  2     B      NULL      2023-02-28  |
|  3     C      NULL      2023-03-31  |
|  4     A      NULL      2023-04-30  |
|  5     B      NULL      2023-05-31  |  
|  6     A      NULL         NULL     | 
|_____________________________________|
```

Then I use the following update code:

```
;WITH From_Table AS
( 
        select CustomerName as CustomerName, 
            [SalesManager], 
            lag([To], 1)  OVER(ORDER BY [CustomerKey] ASC) as TargetDate --, [To]
        FROM Customer
)

UPDATE Customer
SET [Customer].[From] = DATEADD(day, 1, Max_From)

FROM
(
    SELECT dd.CustomerName, dd.SalesManager, dd.[To], dd.[From], MAX(ff.TargetDate) as Max_From
    FROM From_Table AS ff
    INNER JOIN Customer AS dd
    ON ff.CustomerName = dd.CustomerName AND ff.SalesManager = dd.SalesManager
    GROUP BY dd.CustomerName, dd.SalesManager, dd.[To], dd.[From]
    --HAVING dd.[To] IS NULL AND dd.[From] IS NULL
) AS final
INNER JOIN Customer fd
ON fd.CustomerName = final.CustomerName AND fd.SalesManager = final.SalesManager
WHERE fd.[From] IS NULL
```

and I get this result:

```
_______________________________________
|             Customer                |
|=====================================|
| ID   Cust     FROM          TO      |
|------------------------------------ |
|  1     A   2023-04-01   2023-01-31  |
|  2     B   2023-05-01   2023-02-28  |
|  3     C   2023-03-01   2023-03-31  |
|  4     A   2023-04-01   2023-04-30  |
|  5     B   2023-05-01   2023-05-31  |
|  6     A   2023-04-01      NULL     |
|_____________________________________|
```

but what I want to have is the result below:

```
_______________________________________
|             Customer                |
|=====================================|
| ID   Cust     FROM          TO      |
|------------------------------------ |
|  1     A      NULL      2023-01-31  |
|  2     B   2023-02-01   2023-02-28  |
|  3     C   2023-03-01   2023-03-31  |
|  4     A   2023-04-01   2023-04-30  |
|  5     B   2023-05-01   2023-05-31  |  
|  6     A   2023-06-01      NULL     |
|_____________________________________|
```

Do you have any idea how to achieve it?
Also, I want to mention that the dates won't be the end of the month and the start of the month.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this :

`LAG()` to get the the row that precedes the current.

```
UPDATE c
SET [FROM] = newFrom
FROM Customer c
JOIN (
  select ID, 
  DATEADD(day, 1, lag([To]) OVER(ORDER BY ID)) as newFrom
  FROM Customer
) s on s.ID = c.ID;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XgYSKyJD)